# [org-mode]: repeating task in every Mon, Wed, Fri at 18:00, need help with sexp

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp, org-mode

As I had written in title, I need a little help with improvement of this sexp:

```
* TODO remeber about thingie.
  SCHEDULED: <%%(or (= 1 (calendar-day-of-week date)) 
                    (= 3 (calendar-day-of-week date)) 
                    (= 5 (calendar-day-of-week date)))>
```

Now it shows itself in the following days, but I would like to change two things about it:

- How can I also schedule on specific hours (i.e. 18:00 - 20:00) in the following days
- How can I made this task repeat itself, just like it repeats itself with

  `<2010-05-13 Wed +1w>`

  (by repetition I mean something like it automatically logs the closing date and time and comes back to the `TODO` state).

I will be grateful for any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
* TODO remeber about thingie.
  SCHEDULED: <2012-05-07 Mon 18:00 +1w>
  SCHEDULED: <2012-05-09 Wed 18:00 +1w>
  SCHEDULED: <2012-05-11 Fri 18:00 +1w>
```

Comment: This changes all the scheduled dates when it's marked as done by advancing each one week in the future.  That's not a bad thing, I just hoped it would only advance one of the scheduled dates.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, you cannot use diary-sexps for repeating TODO items in org-mode like that.
The work-around is to create three repeating TODO items, and use the normal org-mode date expressions, not diary sexps.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't need to mark task as **DONE** every day, you must simply write:

```
** remeber about thingie 1. 18:00-20:00
   <%%(and (memq (calendar-day-of-week date) '(1 3 5))
           (diary-block 03 26 2012 12 31 2012))>
```

In your case you have to use separated tasks:

```
** TODO remeber about thingie 2-1. 18:00-20:00
   SCHEDULED: <2012-03-26 Mon +1w>
** TODO remeber about thingie 2-3. 18:00-20:00
   SCHEDULED: <2012-03-28 Wed +1w>
** TODO remeber about thingie 2-5. 18:00-20:00
   SCHEDULED: <2012-03-30 Fri +1w>
```

Marking task as **DONE** *(C-c C-t)* your task will be changed automatically to:

```
** TODO remeber about thingie 2-5. 18:00-20:00
   SCHEDULED: <2012-04-06 Fri +1w>
   - State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2012-03-30 Fri 12:34]
   :PROPERTIES:
   :LAST_REPEAT: [2012-03-30 Fri 12:34]
   :END:
```